# Find a matching document based on not matching property in array of objects - MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I'm new to MongoDB or NoSQL, I have set of documents in my Rooms collection,

```
/* 1 */
{
    "roomId" : 1,
    "bookedFor" : [ 
        {
            "startTime" : 1000,
            "endTime" : 1100
        }, 
        {
            "startTime" : 1300,
            "endTime" : 1400
        }, 
        {
            "startTime" : 1800,
            "endTime" : 1900
        }
    ]
}

/* 2 */
{
    "roomId" : 3,
    "bookedFor" : [ 
        {
            "startTime" : 0900,
            "endTime" : 1000
        }, 
        {
            "startTime" : 1400,
            "endTime" : 1500
        }, 
        {
            "startTime" : 1300,
            "endTime" : 1400
        }
    ]
}

/* 3 */
{
    "roomId" : 2,
    "bookedFor" : [ 
        {
            "startTime" : 1000,
            "endTime" : 1100
        }, 
        {
            "startTime" : 1800,
            "endTime" : 1900
        }, 
        {
            "startTime" : 0900,
            "endTime" : 1000
        }
    ]
}
```

Now what I want to achieve is, I need to find a room, which should is not booked for the requesting time.

For example, If I want to book a room with startTime:1300 and endTime: 1400, it should return 3rd document alone.

**P.S: Any other schema change which solve my problem is also welcomed.**

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

```
db.yourcollection.find( { bookedFor : { $elemMatch : { startTime : 1300, endTime : 1400 } } } ).sort( { roomId : -1 } ).limit(1)
```

Comment: Hi Styvane, it is not working as I expected. It is returning the documents which had booked for 1300 to 1400. And also one more challenge here is, it should return only third document even for 1350 to 1450, since the time clashes the previously booked time. +1 for helping hand. :) Please help me again.

Comment: It's not working. Because, you just updated the sorting order. My 1st concern is, it is returning all documents which has **booked for 1300 - 1400**. But what I expect is it should return only the last document which is **not booked** for 1300 - 1400.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can work out the logic using $lg and $gt operators combined with an $or.
Finding all rooms that are not occupied, ie that do not
1) Have a booking starting during the slot
2) have a booking ending during the slot
3) Have a booking starting before and ending after the slot
4) Have a short booking during the slot

Which in this case would translate to:

```
db.yourcollection
    .find( {bookedFor : {
               $and:[{ 
                 {$not: {$elemMatch :{ startTime : { $gt : 1300, $lt: 1400 }},
                 {$not: {$elemMatch :{ startTime : { $gt : 1300, $lt: 1400 }},
                 {$not: {$elemMatch :{ startTime : { $lt : 1300}, endTime: {$gt: 1400 }}
                 {$not: {$elemMatch :{ startTime : { $gt : 1300}, endTime: {$lt: 1400 }}
               ]} 
    })
```

At least in the [mongo docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/), there is a similar example for elemMatch.
Here is [another link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-user/ImzJOtnrsHU) to negate elemMatch.